# How to get nearest r elements in mxn matrix, for each element

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an `mxn` matrix called `arr`. For each element in `arr`, I want to view all elements (i.e. a submatrix) within r units of that element (including diagonally). e.g. if r=1, the submatrix should be a 3x3 square around the current pixel. The submatrix doesn't necessarily need to be a square (it won't be if the element in question is on the edge of the matrix, for example).

I tried the below with limited success:

```
r=1
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n): 
        print(arr[max(0,i-r-1):min(i+r+1,m), max(0,j-r-1):min(j+r+1,n)])
```

Comment: what do you expect it to show when it is close to the edges? Your slice size may be over the array size

Comment: @DouglasFerreira Just updated to include that. It should still show a submatrix, it just won't be square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = 1
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        start_y = i-r
        end_y = i+ r + 1

        start_x = j - r
        end_x = j + r + 1

        if start_y < 0:
            start_y = 0

        elif end_y >= m:
            end_y = m

        if start_x < 0:
            start_x = 0

        elif end_x >= n:
            end_x = n

        print(arr[start_y: end_y, start_x: end_x])
```

Comment: Should that be `i` instead of `m` and `j` instead of `n` in the first 4 lines of the nested for loop?

Comment: not entirely it seems. The first iteration (i,j=0) produces a 1x1 submatrix (the element itself).

Comment: yeah, I think your solution was similar (if not the same) as my original one above. Python's slicing is annoying...

Comment: I believe the problem gets resolved if we change to `end_y = i+ r + 1` and `end_x = j + r + 1`. i.e. if we add 1. I'm not sure whether I need to -1 from start_y and start_x as well, but it seems to be working without.

Comment: I have added it in the last edit. And yes there is no need for -1 in the start index